# CoffeeScript For Loop won't stop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to create a for loop that cycles through the first 5 elements in an array. When I go to run my program instead of only displaying the first 5 elements and then stopping, it displays 5 elements and then continues to display those same five elements infinitely. It just continues on and on spitting out those 5 items. Why isn't it stopping? Here is my code

```
update: (output, domEl) ->
  data  = JSON.parse(output)
  items = data.items
  $domEl = $(domEl)

  list = $domEl.find('ol')
  items = items[0..4]
  for i in items
    $("<li>#{i.summary}</li>").appendTo(list)
```

Comment: sounds like your update is triggering multiple times

Comment: whats update hooked to?

Comment: I'm writing a widget for Ubersicth: http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/. I have looked at other widget code and they don't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "refreshFrequency" variable that I declared at the top of the script. If I move it below the required 'command' variable it fixes the problem.